# How to transfer high pressure hydrogen using flexible pipes?

Tags: hydraulics, pipelines, process-engineering, piping, compressed-gases

The task is to transfer hydrogen (high pressure gas > 400 bars) from offshore platform to land. To do so we have to use flexible pipes but for high pressure and high flow rate I'm afraid we can't find large diametre flexibles (4-8 inches). What is the solution? Maybe devide the flow into many flexibles in parallel and unite them into a manifold and then connect the manifold to steel pipes?

Comment: Why not use steel like the other lines ?

Comment: Because the platform is moving and travels to different locations (connect/disconnect). Flexibles are inevitable from platform to the port.

Comment: Still done with steel . Coil tubing is one option.

Comment: Off shore gas production drills wells from a drill platform then installs permanent production platform.

Comment: Japan uses large flexible high-pressure gas lines extensively, because of earth-quake movement. Maybe your requirements are different?

Answer (score 0):

flexible plumbing is very expensive and rigid steel pipe is very cheap in comparison. The optimum solution is to use as much cheap rigid steel piping as possible with as few expensive flexible joints as possible inserted every few hundred yards or so.

Comment: Some detail on why this is the optimum solution would improve this answer.

Comment: Ridged is relative . I have heard of pipe pulled hundreds of feet to the side by inadvertent anchor drags ( US Gulf coast, relatively crowded in some areas.)

Comment: And coil tubing  (up to about 3")  is rolled on a large coil like a rubber hose ( and unrolled, possible many times).